# How to clear error message when using Blazor validation

Tags: blazor

Is there any way to clear the error for a specific field when using using Blazor validation ?

I tried something like the following, but it does not clear the error message :

```
MyEditContext.MarkAsUnmodified(MyEditContext.Field("Filename"));
```

Comment: Share the full code to understand better.  Are you storing messages in ValidationMessageStore ?

Comment: There's a chance you just have to call StateHasChanged()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for the same thing, you can do the following and it will clear the existing error message for a particular field :

```cs
MyEditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(MyEditContext.Field("MyFieldName"));
```

Comment: This is not going to clear the error message on the field, it will reevaluate the field, if the error persist the message will continue to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

maybe someone else will need it.

For clear all error create new EditContext:

1)Dont't use in form: EditForm Model="@LoginModel"

2)Use:  EditForm EditContext="editContext"

3)For clear all error create new EditContext:

```
protected void CreateNewLoginModel()
{
    LoginModel = new();
    editContext = new EditContext(LoginModel);
}
```